# single data is getting repeating 18 times in listview

Tags: android, json, listview

i have an app in which i am retrieving data from json and showing it in listview,i getting an problem only single data is getting visible in the list,i tried to figure out the problem but get nothing,where i am going wrong please help me to sort it out.In log i am getting different data but on adding it to array list getting single data repition multiple time,and no other item is visible.

**BussinessActivity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bussiness_details);


        Log.i("DetailsUrl.Bussinessurl", DetailsUrl);

        new JSONAsyncTask().execute(DetailsUrl);
         weblink=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtweb);
         list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);


        list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                        //catagery.get(position).getcategory_name(),
                        //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        });

    }

    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(BussinessDetails.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            catageries = new ArrayList<ProfileDetails>();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                // ------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);

                    JSONObject jarray = jsono.getJSONObject("business");
                     ProfileDetails category = new ProfileDetails();
                    //String business_id = jarray.getString("business_id");

                    //Log.i("business_id", business_id);

                    //String business_name = jarray.getString("business_name");

                    //Log.i("business_name", business_name);
                    String web_site = jarray.getString("web_site");
                    category.setData1(web_site);
                    category.setNumber2(web_site);
                    //weblink.setText(web_site);
                    Log.i("web_site", web_site);
                    //String about_business = jarray.getString("about_business");

                    //Log.i("web_site", web_site);
                    JSONObject phn = jarray.getJSONObject("Phones");

                        List<String> listArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Iterator iter = phn.keys();

                    int count=0;
                    while(iter.hasNext())
                    {
                         String key = (String)iter.next();
                       // listArray.add((String)iter.next());
                        Log.i("Name",key);

                        count +=1;
                       // String key = (String)iter.next();

                      //  Object o = phn.get(key);
                        if( phn.get(key) instanceof JSONArray ){

                            JSONArray arry = phn.getJSONArray(key);


                            int size = arry.length();
                            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                                String CC_info_left = arry.getJSONObject(i).getString("CC_info_left");
                                Log.i("CC_info_left", CC_info_left);


                                String CC_info_right = arry.getJSONObject(i).getString("CC_info_right");
                                Log.i("CC_info_right", CC_info_right);

                                String CC_info_short_desc = arry.getJSONObject(i).getString("CC_info_short_desc");
                                Log.i("CC_info_short_desc", CC_info_short_desc);


                                String CC_info_short_desc_align = arry.getJSONObject(i).getString("CC_info_short_desc_align");
                                Log.i("CC_info_short_desc_align", CC_info_short_desc_align);


                                category.setName(key);
                                category.setNumber1(CC_info_right);
                                category.setData(CC_info_left);
                                category.setDescription(CC_info_short_desc);
                                // Log.i("category", category.toString());

                                catageries.add(category);
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    //Collections.sort(listArray);
                    // System.out.println(listArray);
                    JSONObject  EmailAddress = jarray.getJSONObject("Emails");
                    Iterator iter1 = EmailAddress.keys();

                    int count1=0;
                    while(iter1.hasNext()){
                         String key1 = (String)iter1.next();

                        Log.i("Name1",key1);

                        count +=1;
                       // String key = (String)iter.next();

                      //  Object o = phn.get(key);
                        if( EmailAddress.get(key1) instanceof JSONArray ){

                            JSONArray arry1 = EmailAddress.getJSONArray(key1);


                            int size1 = arry1.length();
                            for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {

                        String CC_info_left1 =arry1.getJSONObject(i).getString("CC_info_left");



                        String CC_info_right1 = arry1.getJSONObject(i).getString("CC_info_right");

                        String CC_info_short_desc1 = arry1.getJSONObject(i).getString("CC_info_short_desc");

                        String CC_info_short_desc_align1 =arry1.getJSONObject(i).getString("CC_info_short_desc_align");
                        category.setEmail(key1);
                        category.setEmailleft(CC_info_left1);
                        category.setEmailright(CC_info_right1);
                        category.setEmailDesc(CC_info_short_desc1);
                        catageries.add(category);

                            }

                            }
                    }

                    // /}
                    // }
                    return true;
                }

                // ------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (result == false){
                Toast.makeText(BussinessDetails.this,
                        "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }else{
                adapter = new DetailAdaptor(BussinessDetails.this, R.layout.list_details, catageries);

                list1.setAdapter(adapter);
                //emailAdaptor=new EmailAdaptor(BussinessDetails.this, R.layout.list_details, catagery);
                //list2.setAdapter(emailAdaptor);


            }
        }
    }
```

**DetailAdaptor**

```
public class DetailAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<ProfileDetails> {
    ArrayList<ProfileDetails> detailList;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public DetailAdaptor(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ProfileDetails> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        detailList = objects;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);

            holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_from_phone);
            holder.tvData2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data_from_phone1);
            holder.tvData1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data_from_phone2);
            holder.tvDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data_from_phone3);
            holder.email = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_for_email);
            holder.email_left = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.email_left);
            holder.email_right = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.email_right);
            holder.emailDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.email_desc);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } 

        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvName.setText(detailList.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvDescription.setText(detailList.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.tvData1.setText(detailList.get(position).getNumber1());
        holder.tvData2.setText(detailList.get(position).getData());
        holder.email.setText(detailList.get(position).getEmail());
        holder.email_left.setText(detailList.get(position).getEmailleft());
        holder.email_right.setText(detailList.get(position).getEmailright());
        holder.emailDescription.setText(detailList.get(position).getEmailDesc());
        return v;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageview;
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvDescription;
        public TextView tvData1;
        public TextView tvData2;
        public TextView email;
        public TextView emailDescription;
        public TextView email_left;
        public TextView email_right;

    }

}
```

**ProfileDetails**

```
public class ProfileDetails {

    private String title;
    private String email;
    private String email_left;
    private String email_right;
    private String email_desc;
    private String number1;
    private String number2;
    private String description;
    private String detail1;
    private String detail2;
    //private String children;
    //private String image;

    public ProfileDetails() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ProfileDetails(String name,String num, String num2, String desc, 
            String data1, String data2,String emails,String emailleft ,String emailright,String emaildesc) {
        super();
        title = name;
        description = desc;
        number1 = num;
        number2 = num2;
        detail1 = data1;
        detail2 = data2;
        email =emails;
        email_left=emailleft;
        email_right=emailright;
        email_desc=email_desc;
        //this.children = children;
        //this.image = image;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        title = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String ename) {
        email = ename;
    }
    public String getEmailleft() {
        return email_left;
    }

    public void setEmailleft(String Eleft) {
        email_left = Eleft;
    }
    public String getEmailright() {
        return email_right;
    }

    public void setEmailright(String Eright) {
        email_right = Eright;
    }
    public String getEmailDesc() {
        return email_desc;
    }

    public void setEmailDesc(String Edesc) {
        email_desc = Edesc;
    }


    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return detail1;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        detail1 = data;
    }
    public String getData1() {
        return detail2;
    }

    public void setData1(String data) {
        detail2 = data;
    }
    public String getNumber1() {
        return number1;
    }

    public void setNumber1(String num) {
        number1 = num;
    }

    public String getNumber2() {
        return number2;
    }

    public void setNumber2(String num) {
        number2 = num;
    }

    /*public String getSpouse() {
        return spouse;
    }

    public void setSpouse(String spouse) {
        this.spouse = spouse;
    }

    public String getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(String children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
*/
}
```

**BussinessDetail.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rel1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Start a New ChaBu"
            android:textColor="#030303"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chatIcon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/new_chabu_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_details" >
    </ListView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

**List_details**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#E6E6E6" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Customer Care Numbers"
            android:textColor="#030303"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/txtlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line4"
        android:background="#E6E6E6" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_from_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="#E6E6E6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtlay"
        android:background="#E6E6E6" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data_from_phone1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="#E6E6E6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data_from_phone2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data_from_phone3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/data_from_phone1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/whitelay"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/whitelay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/whitelay"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#E6E6E6" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Customer Care Emails"
            android:textColor="#030303"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/txtlay1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line5"
        android:background="#E6E6E6" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_for_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="#E6E6E6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtlay1"
         android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line6"
        android:background="#E6E6E6" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="#E6E6E6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/email_left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="" />
    </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel4"
         android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#E6E6E6" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="About Us"
            android:textColor="#030303"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title5"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/line11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line10"
         android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#E6E6E6" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/about_us"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Website"
            android:textColor="#030303"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel6"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
         android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="ffdhjggjhkkghjg"
        android:textColor="#030303"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtweb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="ffdhjggjhkkghjg"
         android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="#030303"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtweb"
         android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does your `detailList` look good after initialization - i.e. does it contain 18 unique items?

Comment: If you put two log-lines in the Adapter - one right after `if v==null` and one right after `else`, how many times does each of them get called before you do any scrolling in the ui?

Comment: @  Nilzor it is returing me same item after intialization only

Comment: Hm.. that's a red flag.  It should be creating at least one new View for each visual element visible at the same time. I.e. if there's room for 5 elements on the screen at any given time, *at least* five Views should be generated by the system. I don't have the answer yet, but maybe you could post the XML?

Comment: @  Nilzor i post my xml files too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create Object of category once in pre execute  and then you not create new object so the category last value set in the array list everytime you create category object in loop and try it is working

Comment: if i'll add category in loop then my other loop that is fetching data from json will not get Category ..how will i add all the things at a time..??

Comment: create another model and add this model to your current model and then you can add the data

Comment: ya you can create new model and in this model create getter ans setter for another model value

Comment: but will not get problem in adding it arraylist..??coz m getting it

Comment: in profile detail model  class you create  another getting and setting method of category

Comment: sry i create another model class,but not inside the previous model class

Comment: Thank you so much i get the data.but last thing why i am getting 7 blank cells too after data filled ?